# how to change Behat path from Public folder to different folder name

Tags: laravel, behat

I am having an issue with testing a Laravel app I have inherited.

The folder that is usually labelled as **"public"** was renamed to **"html"**.

The app itself works fine, but when **Behat tests run** it still **looks for a public folder**.  I have been **working around** it by just **copying the "html" file and renaming it as public**, but I would like to just fix this so I can get some other co workers testing this app.

I have **looked in the Behat documentation** and was unable to find it.  I also googled this quite a bit but did not find anything addressing it.

Anyone know how to **set this path** so instead of looking for a folder called "public" I can change it to look for a folder called "html."

The exact error I get is

```
Warning: file_get_contents(/Library/WebServer/Documents/myApp/myApp/public/build/rev-manifest.json): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Library/WebServer/Documents/thirdspace-app/thirdspace/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php line 668
```

So the **public**  in the above path needs to be **html**.

That code that is being referenced in that error looks like below

```
 if ( ! function_exists('elixir'))
{

  function elixir($file)
  {
      static $manifest = null;

      if (is_null($manifest))
      {
          $manifest = json_decode(file_get_contents(public_path().'/build/rev-manifest.json'), true);
      }

      if (isset($manifest[$file]))
      {
            return '/build/'.$manifest[$file];
      }

      throw new InvalidArgumentException("File {$file} not defined in asset manifest.");
  }
}
```

I do not really want to change this however because I think this will affect the app itself.  I just want to send the test looking for html in stead of public.  I really just want to make sure the solution to ths only affects the tests, not the app itself.

Comment: Can you use a symlink? `ln -s /path/to/html /path/to/public`

Comment: Could you explain to me what that does exactly? More specifically, that does not change any path ways as far as the app is concerned, does it just point anything looking for "public" to "html"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This uses the Laravel helper function `public_path()` which will always return a path expecting a directory called `public`.

There are a few different ways to overwrite this, but this is probably the simplest. In order that this runs before Behat, define this in `bootstrap/app.php`:

```
$app->bind('path.public', function() {
    return base_path().'/html';
});
```

Comment: Ah okay, you didn't mention that you were already overwriting it in index.php (unless it is now default in the newest Laravel patch, but I think I'm up to date). Could you try my second suggestion that I just added, about putting that block in `bootstrap/app.php`. I'm pretty sure that this is the problem and now we just have to find the right spot to overwrite that helper function before Behat uses it.

Comment: That looks like it worked.  Thanks so much, you have no idea how much this just improved my work day.

Comment: Okay glad to hear it! I edited my answer so now it only shows the correct version, in case someone would think the first version works with Behat.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how Laravel uses behat tests, so this a rather generic answer. I do not know why the behat tests would depend on that folder other than looking for static content (e.g. uploads) stored there. Maybe you can add an example output from a failing behat tests? The 2 options I think are most likely to contain the path are:

- If it was specified in one of your contexts you should probably look there. The are usually placed in a subfolder of `features/` where all your feature-files reside.
- Otherwise Behat is configured via `behat.yml` in the project root. You might want to check the [paths](http://docs.behat.org/en/v2.5/guides/7.config.html#paths) and [contexts](http://docs.behat.org/en/v2.5/guides/7.config.html#context) (or rather their parameters) defined in there.